# How to map a vertex in a cylinder to plane?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

[image]I have a cylinder  that has rectangular box  regions to mark the leakage problem. The location of the rectangular box is determined by its initial position in the longitudinal axis and its initial position in the circumferential axis in degree. The length  and width (in degrees, from 0° to 360°) of the boxes are also available.

How to convert this cylinder to plane surface so that I could locate the location of rectangular boxes in 2D plane?
Here I have  three rectangles on the surface.

Comment: I don't understand what "leakage" means in this context. Do you mean that it is holes with a loss of something ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yeah. There are holes.

Comment: Instead of cylindrical coord. you need only consider polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ in a sectional plane. Right ?

Comment: @JeanMarie  I am not sure